# Netlogo: How to make turtles stop moving when a condition (suitable patch is found) is met?

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to construct a model that simulates patterns of housing selection in a given area.

I am asking turtles to seek a settlement patch in radius-3 that offers the most resource, if one is found, they should settle there and stop moving; otherwise, they should move to somewhere else and stop moving. However, no matter what I do, no turtle seems to stop; every turtle is constantly moving around regardless of whether a settlement is found.

Below is my seek-settlement module under "go". Please advise on how to make a turtle stop moving if a condition is met (i.e. a suitable settlement is found)? I tried sticking “stop” in various places but with no difference.

```
to seek-settlement-1
  ask turtles with [wealth >= com] 
  [
    ifelse any? patches in-radius 3 with [pcolor = green and count      turtles-here = 0]
    [   ;;; if there are any neighboring empty green patches with resource larger than wealth of the turtle
      move-to max-one-of patches in-radius 3 with [pcolor = green and count turtles-here = 0] [resource] ;+ (0.5 * count turtles in-radius 3 with [color = blue])]
      set settlement patch-here   ;;; move to the one with the most utility (defined as an even combination of resource and number of blue turtles in radius 1) and settle there
      stop   ;;; this stop appears to make no difference
    ]

    [right random 360
     forward 3
     set wealth (wealth - com)
     stop]   ;;; this stop appears to make no difference

    if settlement != nobody
    [
     set wealth (wealth - com + (0.5 * [resource] of settlement))   ;;; update the turtle's wealth by subtracting the cost of movement and adding 20% of the resource of the patch here
     ask settlement
     [set resource (0.5 * resource)]   ;;; update the settlement patch's resource by subtracting 20%
stop   ;;; this stop appears to make no difference
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Please note that I'm not trying to make the whole simulation stop, which requires a stop command in "go". I am trying to make individual turtles stop moving once they find a suitable patch.

Answer (score 0):

Please review the documentation of `stop`:
http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/stop.html 
The `stop` will merely exit your `ask`.

Your code does not match your description.  Trying to follow your description, I get something like the following:

```
globals [com]
patches-own [resource]
turtles-own [wealth settlement]

to setup
  ca
  set com 10
  crt 50 [
    set wealth random 500
    set settlement nobody
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  ask patches [
    if random-float 1 < 0.2 [set resource 100 set pcolor green]
  ]
end

to go
  ;you can change the filter any way you wish
  ask turtles with [wealth >= com and settlement = nobody] [seek-settlement]
end

to seek-settlement
  let _candidates (patches in-radius 3 with [pcolor = green and count turtles-here = 0])
  if any? _candidates [ 
    set settlement max-one-of _candidates [resource]
    move-to settlement 
  ]  
  ifelse (settlement = nobody) [ ;this conditional shd probably be in a separate proc
    right random 360
    forward 3
    set wealth (wealth - com)
  ][
    set wealth (wealth - com + (0.5 * [resource] of settlement))
    ask settlement [set resource (0.5 * resource)] 
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried incorporating what you suggested, but my problem persists...     I made sure to ask those turtles with [settlement = nobody] to just find any random black patch in radius-3 and settle there.       I understand how "stop" wouldn't help. But I still don't know why my turtles keep moving even though they should all settle somewhere.

Comment: You need to debug your code.  (E.g., http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/How-to-debug-td4863236.html) I've added details for a self-contained example.